# PPTP defaultroute. Want to route all traffic via ppp interface

Tags: linux, networking, routing, pptp, point-to-point-protocol

I'm experiencing a problem described here: http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#lots_of_data. If I use defaultroute in peer conf or manually add

```
route add default dev ppp0
```

there are tons of traffic in TX: in `ifconfig` so perhaps it loops somehow. I'd like to set it up so that I run `pon ru` and it automatically routes all non-local traffic through ppp0.

Here are my current configs.

1. /etc/ppp/peers/ru:

> ```
> connect /bin/true
> plugin "/usr/local/lib/pppd/2.4.5/pptp.so"
> pptp_server ru1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
> user "username"
> password "password"
> noauth
> nobsdcomp
> nodeflate
> remotename ru
> ipparam ru
> require-mppe-128
> usepeerdns
> nodefaultroute
> persist
> mtu 1528
> mru 1528
> ```

2. ip-up scripts: http://pastebin.com/7d4wAe3a
3. ifplugd scripts: http://pastebin.com/e0NAsthY
4. here is how routing looks like after `pon ru` :

> ```
> root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# route
> Kernel IP routing table
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
> default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
> 192.168.39.81   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
> 192.168.178.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
> ```

5. here is ifconfig after `pon ru`:

> ```
> root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ifconfig
> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:19:c2:bb
>           inet addr:192.168.178.35  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:56356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:54433 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>           RX bytes:7269518 (6.9 MiB)  TX bytes:8972796 (8.5 MiB)
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>           RX packets:962 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:962 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>           RX bytes:83039 (81.0 KiB)  TX bytes:83039 (81.0 KiB)
>
> ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
>           inet addr:31.6.12.130  P-t-P:192.168.39.81  Mask:255.255.255.255
>           UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1396  Metric:1
>           RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:9436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
>           RX bytes:84 (84.0 B)  TX bytes:13093786 (12.4 MiB)
>
> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:ca:72:6d:a4
>           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# route
> ```

eth0 - my internal network interface going into AVM Frtiz!box router. wlan0 is not active at all. See huge numbers in TX in ppp0 which is the problem itself, this 12.4 mb is just a few seconds after the niterface is up.

**UPDATE**

Here is tcpdump output when I add default route thruogh ppp0: http://pastebin.com/7nUyLAex

Answer (score 0):

/etc/ppp/peers/ru: there is a nodefaultroute parameter in this file. As far as I know, it needs to be defaultroute.